# Read .csv File into Multiple database tables while filling the dependencies between them

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, csvhelper

I'm doing a project(ASP.Net Razor Pages) and I'm really stuck. So I have this method that reads a .csv file looking like this:

| Id | Foods | Categories | Actions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Acerola | Fruit | "DNA Protection, Immunity" |
| 2 | Almond Butter | Sweets | DNA Protection |
| 3 | Almonds | "Legumes, Nuts, Beans" | "Angiogenesis Antiangiogenic, DNA Protection" |
| 4 | Aged Garlic | Vegetables | Immunity |
| 5 | Anchovies | Vegetables | "Angiogenesis Antiangiogenic, Regeneration, DNA Protection" |

Before each "," it's a Table in the database, and the last column accepts multiple values.

The view:

```
...
    <form asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="Import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="for-group">
           <label class="form-label">Upload file</label>
           <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control"/>
           <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-primary">Upload</button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

...

The "Controller"

```
public void UploadtoDb(IFormFile file)
{
    var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {

        var categoryRecords = new List<Category>();
        var ActionsRecords = new List<Actions>();
        var foodRecords = new List<Food>();
        var csv = csvReader.Read().ToString().Split(',');
        csvReader.ReadHeader();
        csvReader.Configuration.BadDataFound.Equals(true);

        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var catRecords = new Category
            {
                CategoryName = csvReader.GetField("Categories")
            };
            categoryRecords.Add(catRecords);

            var fRecords = new Food
            {
                FoodName = csvReader.GetField("Foods")
            };

            foodRecords.Add(fRecords);
            foodRecords.Select(x => x.FoodName).Distinct();

            var actionsRecords = new Actions
            {
                ActionName = csvReader.GetField("Actions")
            };
            ActionsRecords.Add(actionsRecords);
            ActionsRecords.Select(x => x.ActionName).Distinct();
        }
        categoryRecords.Select(x => x.CategoryName).Distinct();
        var uniqueCategories = categoryRecords.GroupBy(p => p.CategoryName)
                   .Select(grp => grp.First())
                   .ToArray();
        foreach (var category in uniqueCategories)
        {
            _ctx.Categories.Add(category);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        foreach (var food in foodRecords)
        {
            _ctx.Foods.Add(food);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        foreach (var action in ActionsRecords)
            _ctx.Actions.Add(action);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Wherever I get to the foods, it asks me for the categoryId which is from the Categories table/Third column in the file.

I also tried with some queries and Linq i.e: `food.CategoryId = _ctx.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id=food.Category.Id)`

Pictures of the errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HykmY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUNqv.jpg)

GiTHubCli code:
gh repo clone joaoFerreiragHub/ProjetoFinal

Link: https://github.com/joaoFerreiragHub/ProjetoFinal.git

Is there a way that CsvHelper can help me out with sorting this into the tables?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error message? For example on which line the problem is encountered.

Comment: If you want to use EF Core, *don't* call SaveChanges all the time. Call it only once at the very end. ORMs like EF Core and NHibernate were never meant for data loading though - O means Object, and there are no Objects involved here, only rows. Loading all CSVs in memory is very inefficient and simply won't scale to large files.

Comment: CsvHelper doesn't generate relations between objects either, your own code would have to do this. Once you match objects, you can simply `Add` all the *root* objects to the DbContext and call `SaveChanges` once. EF Core will generate the SQL statements that insert the parent and child rows and fix their IDs

Comment: Apart from that, the code in the question is hard to understand and actually discards the results of operations. For example, the result of `categoryRecords.Select(x => x.CategoryName).Distinct();` isn't stored anywhere. A new `Food` object is created for every source row which will result in a *lot* of duplicates. What are you trying to do ? What does the source file and target tables look like? Are there any keys involved? Any existing data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this quickly, the best way would be to upload the CSV file "as is" into a staging table, say "StagingFoods".

```sql
CREATE TABLE StagingFoods
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Foods nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Categories nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Actions nvarchar(1000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StagingFoods PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

*Unfortunately, EntityFramework doesn't have a good way to do bulk inserts, but you could try a nuget third party extension like [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)*.

```cs
var records = csv.GetRecords<StagingFoods>();
_ctx.BulkInsert(records);
```

Then use straight SQL to create your Categories, Foods and Actions.  You can use the SQL in your EntityFramework code using [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-6.0). If you have a lot of data, this will be a **lot** faster than inserting them one at a time.

**Category**

```cs
_ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@"
Insert into
    Category(CategoryName)
select
    Categories
from
    StagingFoods sf
        left join Category c
        on sf.Categories = c.CategoryName
where
    c.Id is null
group by
    Categories
");
```

**Food**

```cs
_ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@"
Insert into
    Foods(FoodName,CategoryId)
select
    sf.Foods
   ,c2.Id
from
    StagingFoods sf
        left join Foods f
            join Category c1
            on f.CategoryId = c1.Id and sf.Categories = c1.CategoryName
        on sf.Foods = f.FoodName 
        join Category c2
        on sf.Categories = c2.CategoryName
where
    f.Id is null
group by
    Categories
   ,Foods
");
```

I'll let you figure out how to do `Actions`.

When you are finished inserting all of the data in the tables, you can [truncate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) your staging table.

```cs
_ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE StagingFoods");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for this I'll give you a try.